# Find $r\in\Bbb Z$ for $4^{451}\equiv r\mod 7$

Tags: congruences

I guess I should start by saying that $4\equiv 11\mod 7$, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Is it possible to do without using Fermat's theorem?

Thank you.

Comment: You got $4$ different solutions for your question. Hope this makes you happy !

Comment: @lsp at least every answer reach the same 4.

Comment: P.S. Direct way : $4^{451}=33810849992682575766549746234657062817206228866311777416189485377707129763630391006362704376810060025259161279568456235448470243808171874384034494621628132922136747775936325386798817131291292227393550906125516057865473810736099951285657401521090334495330469177455231893504 = 4 + 7 \cdot 4830121427526082252364249462093866116743746980901682488027069339672447109090055858051814910972865717894165897081208033635495749115453124912004927803089733274590963967990903626685545304470184603913364415160788008266496258676585707326522485931584333499332924168207890270500$

Comment: @LeeNeverGup, how did you manage to do it?

Comment: @IndrayudhRoy There is a nice program named [pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), which does such kind of calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\displaystyle4=2^2,4^{451}=(2^2)^{451}=2^{902}$

Now, $\displaystyle2^3=8\equiv1\pmod7$ and $902\equiv2\pmod3$

$\displaystyle\implies2^{902}=(2^3)^{300}\cdot2^2\equiv1^{300}\cdot2^2\pmod7$

Comment: I don't understand what use is this: $902\equiv2\pmod3$

Comment: @user126638, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: Did you use $\mod 3$ because you needed $2^3$?

Comment: @user126638, yes $1$ or $-1$ are the easiest to deal with in mudulo

Answer (score 1):

$$4^{451}=2^{902}=4(2^{900})=4(7+1)^{300}$$
From binomial expansion, we can say that $7$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when it divides $(7+1)^{300}$.Hence:
$$4(7+1)^{300}=4(7k+1)=7l+4$$
So you can conclude that $r=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Note $(4^0, 4^1, 4^2, 4^3) \mod 7 \equiv (1,4,16,64) \mod 7 \equiv (1,4,2,1)$ so there is a cycle of 3. Now $4^{451} = 4 \cdot 4^{3 \cdot 150}$ so you will make $150$ cycles from $1$ and come back to $4$. The remainder should be $4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\ 2^{\large 3}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{\large 2(\color{#c00}{451})}\!\equiv 2^{\large \color{}2},\,$ by $\,{\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ \color{#c00}{451}\equiv 4\!+\!5\!+\!1\equiv \color{#c00}1,\,$ by $\,10\equiv 1.$

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way too,

$4 \ \equiv -3 \ (mod \ 7)$

$4^2 \ \equiv \ 9$

$4^2 \ \equiv \ 2$

$4^6 \ \equiv \ 8$

$4^6 \ \equiv \ 1$

$4^{450} \ \equiv \ 1$

$4^{451} \ \equiv 4 \ (mod \ 7)$

If we can find congruent to $ \pm 1$  then the problem becomes easier.

UPDATE:

You can also do

$4^3 \ \equiv \ 1 \ (mod \ 7) $

$4^{450} \ \equiv \ 1 $

$4^{451} \ \equiv \ 4 \ (mod \ 7) $